# What is the difference between rev and haveRev with `p4 opened`?

Tags: perforce

I'm examining the Python dictionary returned when running `p4 -G opened` (or if I were using the P4Python API, with `p4.run_opened`).  The results contain both `haveRev` and `rev` entries that indicate the revision number for each file.  What's the difference? (I can't seem to find P4Python API documentation specifically describing `p4.run_opened`.)

I considered that perhaps they'd be different if I edited a file, synced to a later revision, and neglected to run `p4 resolve`, but both `haveRev` and `rev` still seem to be the same in that situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're almost always the same.  They're only different in cases where you have explicitly synced to a revision other than the one that you are currently "working on".  This is so that if you revert, your workspace will be consistent with what you explicitly synced to.

Example:

```
C:\test\999\depot\sam\i\rc\a>p4 edit foo
//depot/sam/i/rc/a/foo#2 - opened for edit

C:\test\999\depot\sam\i\rc\a>p4 -Ztag opened | grep -i rev
... rev 2
... haveRev 2

C:\test\999\depot\sam\i\rc\a>p4 have foo
//depot/sam/i/rc/a/foo#2 - c:\test\999\depot\sam\i\rc\a\foo

C:\test\999\depot\sam\i\rc\a>p4 sync foo#1
//depot/sam/i/rc/a/foo#2 - is opened at a later revision - not changed

C:\test\999\depot\sam\i\rc\a>p4 -Ztag opened | grep -i rev
... rev 2
... haveRev 1

C:\test\999\depot\sam\i\rc\a>p4 have foo
//depot/sam/i/rc/a/foo#1 - c:\test\999\depot\sam\i\rc\a\foo

C:\test\999\depot\sam\i\rc\a>p4 revert foo
//depot/sam/i/rc/a/foo#1 - was edit, reverted
```

Another case where they're different (apart from explicitly syncing after you've opened the file) is if you open the file in such a way that the file is synced implicitly, e.g. with integrate (which implicitly syncs to head by default so that you don't have to do two resolves).  The file will be opened at the head rev in that situation, but revert will bring you back to what you were at before you opened the file, rather than syncing you to head as a (possibly unexpected and unwanted) side effect of opening and reverting the file.

Comment: Ah, syncing to an *earlier* revision.  Does this mean that `rev >= headRev` is always true?

Comment: I think so -- at least I can't think of any way that you could open a revision older than the one that you have.  Syncing forward will increment both (and schedule a resolve as the working rev "rev" is moved forward), and syncing back will reset the haveRev but otherwise won't do anything.